# SSH connection refused via ethernet cable

Tags: ssh, linux, iptables

I try to connect to my Raspberry Pi from my Mac via an ethernet cable. I get: `ssh: connect to host 169.254.32.96 port 22: Connection refused.`

Nmap says this:

```
Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-11-09 10:43 CET
Nmap scan report for 169.254.32.96
Host is up (0.00088s latency).
Not shown: 749 closed ports, 250 filtered ports
PORT   STATE SERVICE
80/tcp open  http
```

When I connect to my Raspberry via WLAN and the Raspberry is connected to my Airport Express then connection via SSH is possible.

Nmap for this case:

```
Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-11-09 10:44 CET
Nmap scan report for 10.0.1.12
Host is up (0.0015s latency).
Not shown: 995 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
80/tcp   open  http
5002/tcp open  rfe
5901/tcp open  vnc-1
6001/tcp open  X11:1
```

I must connect to the Raspberry via ethernet cable for a show case. What do I have to change? I changed the iptable policies already but it didnt work. And I dont know which rules are used first. Additionally, I installed Eclipse Kura, tightvncserver and OpenXC framework. Since I installed those, I got the problems and entries to the iptable I don`t want to have. When I try to flush my iptables the Raspberry is operating at full capacity and unreachable.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Connection refused` means just what it says. You seem to think this has something to do with IP routing, which it does NOT - you would get a not found (or similar message) if this was so.

The most likely cause is `ssh` security settings on your Mac.

See `Connecting a Computer to the Pi` in [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Milliways
But I try to get a connection via link-local. Do I have to disable dhcpcd as well? Because I cannot access the Pi and you wrote in this tutorial that `avahi` is a `zeroconf` implementation...

Comment: @KevinS Do NOT disable `dhcpcd` - it is neither necessary, nor desirable. You may want to check `~/.ssh/known_hosts` on your Mac. You do not state in your question HOW you are trying to connect - I assumed, because you can via LAN, that this is OK.

Comment: Ok. I re-read your tutorial and as stupid as it sounds but with `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local` I was able to connect ......

Comment: how can I access the Raspberry via VNC? A tightvncserver is already running but I get a timeout when I try to access raspberrypi.local:1 with VNCViewer. When I try to get the IP address, I have the one from my Mac preferences: 169.254.114.245 and when I use ifconfig on the Raspberry I get a IPv6 address which I cannot connect to.... @Milliways
I´m so sorry but I`m a newbie with Raspberry Pis and can`t get it to run like I want it...

Comment: @KevinS try `open vnc://pi@raspberrypi.local:5901` I am not sure if this works - I rarely use `vnc`. I know `rsync` doesn't work this way.

Answer (score 0):

I enabled ssh on my pi using `sudo raspi-config` and then followed this: https://mycyberuniverse.com/mac-os/connect-to-raspberry-pi-from-a-mac-using-ethernet.html

Worked a charm.